# Exception when WSO2CEP deploys execution plan with trigger to Storm

Tags: apache-storm, siddhi, wso2-cep

We have WSO2CEP 4.1.0 in cluster distributed mode and Apache Storm. When execution plan of a flow has trigger it can not be deployed to Storm as topology. When I edit execution plan and press 'Add execution plan' button CEP gives me a popup with exception

```
Failed to add execution plan, Exception: Invalid distributed query specified, Error while converting to XML storm query plan. Execution plan: Some-plan Tenant: -1234. No corresponding stream imported for Siddhi stream : SomeTrigger
```

Here is the simplest execution plan that can reproduce this situation.

```
@Plan:name('Some-plan')
@Plan:description('description')
@Plan:statistics('true')
@Plan:trace('true')

@Export('OutputStream:1.0.0')
define stream outputStream (triggered_time long, desc string);

@IndexBy('entity_id')
define table MemoryTable (  entity_id string);

define trigger SomeTrigger at '0 0 0 * * ? *';

@query(name='trigger-query1')
from SomeTrigger
    delete MemoryTable
    on triggered_time  > 0
;

@query(name='trigger-query2')
from SomeTrigger
select
    triggered_time
    , str:concat('Time: ', time:dateFormat(triggered_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as desc
insert into outputStream;
```

How deploy siddhi execution plan with triggers to Apache Storm?

Comment: A jira has being created to report this problem - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CEP-1541

Comment: This is not supported in current released version of WSO2 CEP and will be fixed in next immediate release.